# Polymorphism nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I develop a restful API with nodeJS.

```
    exports.postCreature = function (req, res) {

    var creature = new Creature({
            name: req.body.name, id_user: req.user._id
        });

    creature.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.status(400).send(Error.setError('impossible to save the your creature', err));
        else
            res.status(201).send();
    });
};

//CODE DUPLICATE 
exports.createCreature = function(user, callback) {
    console.log('Creature created');
    var creature = new Creature({
        name: user.username, id_user: user._id
    });

    creature.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
           callback(err, null);
        else
            callback(null, creature);
    });
}
```

The two functions execute the same code but not with the same parameters.
I would like to avoid duplication in my code.

How can do in order to avoid duplication of my code ?

Comment: From your code, it looks like the first argument to either function is an Object, but with different properties (you could check for their presence) and the second argument is an *instanceof* XHR or Function, which would be another way to detect what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create another function to handle the redundancies:

```
function createCreature (creatureName, user, callback) {
    console.log('Creature created');
    var creature = new Creature({
        name: creatureName, id_user: user._id
    });

    creature.save(function (err, creature) {
        if (err)
           callback(err, null);
        else
            callback(null, creature);
    });
}
```

And then in your other functions:

```
exports.postCreature = function (req, res) {
    createCreature(req.body.name, req.user, function (err, creature) {
        if (err)
            res.status(400).send(Error.setError('impossible to save the your creature', err));
        else
            res.status(201).send();
    };
};

exports.createCreature = function(user, callback) {
    console.log('Creature created');
    createCreature (user.username, user, callback);
}
```

Comment: Yay! Glad, I could help!